# ozzo validation in rule returns error for equal values

Tags: go, validation

I have a simple code using `echo` as engine and `ozzo-validation` as request validator.

```
func (a MyRequest) Validate() error {
    return validation.ValidateStruct(
        &a,
        validation.Field(&a.Value,
            validation.Required,
            validation.Length(1, 5),
            validation.Each(validation.NilOrNotEmpty, validation.In([]string{"true", "false"}),
            ),
        ),
    )
}
```

This is the request I send:

```
{"value":["true"]}
```

I get this error from `In` rule:

```
value: (0: must be a valid value.).
```

But when I check the values with `==` and `reflect.DeppEqual`, values are equal:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual([]string{"true", "false"}[0], a.Value[0]))
fmt.Println([]string{"true", "false"}[0] == a.Value[0])


output:
true
true
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @mkopriva that was the case. Thank you. Would you please post it as an answer, so I can mark it as the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `validation.Each(validation.In([]string{"true", "false"}))` will compare each element in the `Value` slice against the slice provided to `validate.In`, i.e. `[]string{"true", "false"}`.

Use `validation.In("true", "false")` to compare each element in the `Value` slice against the individual values in `validate.In`.